# Scale function not outputting number to variable?

Tags: python, tkinter, global-variables, scrollbar

So for some reason the scale function in tkinter doesn't want to output the number on the scale. All i receive is either 0.0 or nothing. It seems to be to do with the GUI and calling functions through the GUI. Written and run in python 3.4.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import messagebox

iterations=30

def settings():
    global itervar, iterscale
    sGui = Tk()
    itervar = DoubleVar()

    iterscale = Scale(sGui, orient="horizontal", from_=1, to=1000, variable=itervar)
    iterscale.pack()

    iterbutton = Button(sGui, text="Save Settings", command=saveSettings)
    iterbutton.pack()

    sGui.mainloop()

def saveSettings():
    global iterations
    iterations = itervar.get()
    print(iterations)

def doNothing():
    pass

def main():
    global root, version
    root= Tk()

    menu = Menu(root)
    root.config(menu=menu)

    fileMenu = Menu(menu)
    menu.add_cascade(label="File", menu=fileMenu)
    fileMenu.add_command(label="Quit", command=quit)

    benchmarkMenu = Menu(menu)
    menu.add_cascade(label="Benchmark", menu=benchmarkMenu)
    benchmarkMenu.add_command(label="Run [All]", command=doNothing)
    benchmarkMenu.add_separator()
    benchmarkMenu.add_command(label="Settings", command=settings)

    root.mainloop()

#Main
main()
```

I have tried the functions `settings` and `saveSettings` on their own and they work fine, but when i call it through the GUI it doesn't seem to work.

Any ideas on the problem, my only solution would be have the `settings` function and `saveSettings` function in a different file and then run that file externally with `os.startfile("etc...")`

Comment: why do you call `sGui.mainloop()` in the `settings` function?

Comment: so that the settings window stays open when run ?!?!

Comment: .... oh it is another `Tk` instance... ok you need to change it to a `Toplevel` so that it will exist as another window to the main program.

Comment: topmost just allows the window to stay in front of the main GUI

Comment: FWIW, you shouldn't have more than one root `Tk()` window in a program, and you mustn't have more than one `mainloop` call.

Comment: What effects does this have though

Comment: @TomCupis the two `Tk` instances are considered two completely seperate applications, itervar is giving you `0.0` because it is implied part of the first application and can't associate with the `iterscale`, **your error is the effect of having two `Tk` instances.**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Minimal fix: change this

```
itervar = DoubleVar()
```

to this:

```
itervar = DoubleVar(sGui)
```

Because you have two root applications (`root` and `sGui` are both instances of `Tk`) the implied parent widget for `itervar` is the first one created, being `root` so tkinter gets confused when you specify it as the variable for a completely different application.

But I would **highly** recommend using a `Toplevel` instance to keep the windows a part of the same program:

```
sGui = Toplevel(root)
...
#sGui.mainloop() #no longer need this
```

although if you want to be able to run the setting window *without* the main one you might consider making all your visible windows `Toplevel`s and make the actual root hidden:

```
                # I'm not sure if you want to call it this
abs_root = Tk() # but you are already using root
abs_root.withdraw() #hide the window
```

Then make `root = Toplevel(abs_root)`

---

You coud phase out the variable all together by using `.get`ing the scale directly:

```
iterations = iterscale.get()
```