# How can the response of a Button go to an Entry in Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to generate the output of each Button click to an Entry, each time I press generate button the output shows up in the console, but I want it to show in the GUI so I tried to add the command `command=gen` to the Entry and it gives me an error, it seems like Entry's don't accept the argument command, but I'm not too sure if it's just a syntax error, is there another way of displaying the output of the Button click on the Gui? The reason why I wanted it to be an Entry is because it provides a perfect rectangular shape with white inside the box which is perfect for generating things.

```
from Tkinter import * 

def gen():
    print ("testetstesttesttest")

window = Tk()
window.geometry("500x300")
window.title("TestGUI")
botton = Button(window, text="Generate ids",command=gen).place(x=210,y=160)
textbox = Entry(window, command=gen).place(x=210,y=100)
window.mainloop()
```

The error I receive:

```
(widgetName, self._w) + extra + self._options(cnf))
_tkinter.TclError: unknown option "-command"
```

Comment: you may want to look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21592630/why-do-my-tkinter-widgets-get-stored-as-none) since `(textbox is None)-> True`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to set the text of the entry directly. As shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35165723/1730261), a `StringVar` is one way to go about this.

```
entryText = StringVar(window)
```

Then, in the your command:

```
def gen():
    entryText.set("testtesttesttest")
```

Putting it all together:

```
from Tkinter import * 

def gen():
    entryText.set("testtesttesttest")

window = Tk()
window.geometry("500x300")
window.title("TestGUI")
entryText = StringVar(window)
botton = Button(window, text="Generate ids",command=gen).place(x=210,y=160)
textbox = Entry(window, textvariable = entryText).place(x=210,y=100)
window.mainloop()
```

Comment: this doesn't produce an error but it doesn't work, every time I click the button nothing happens, I saw that question before I posted my question.

Comment: @Francesc I tried this right now – the first time I click the button, the entry is populated with the text. Every click after, though, it just fills it with the same text, so nothing changes.

Comment: @Francesc, do you by any chance have more then one Tk instance? you will need to make `entryText` part of the same application with `StringVar(window)`

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36699249/scale-function-not-outputting-number-to-variable/36699481#36699481

Comment: I wouldn't say the `StringVar` is the _best_ way, just _a_ way. You don't need a `StringVar` since you can insert text directly into the widget.